# Lambda function for creating an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, keyerror

I ran my code to create an EC2 instance but I keep getting this error.

```
  "errorMessage": "'message'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
```

The full code

```
import boto3
import os

AMI = os.environ['AMI']
INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ['INSTANCE_TYPE']
KEY_NAME = os.environ['KEY_NAME']
SUBNET_ID = os.environ['SUBNET_ID']
REGION = os.environ['AWS_REGION']

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event['message']


    instance = ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='terminate', 
        UserData=init_script
    )

    instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    print instance_id

    return instance_id
```

What could be triggering this key error?

As an environmental variable, am I supposed to use the full key name including its file type.
Ex: "key.pem" instead of "key"

Comment: Show us the rest of the code

Comment: @Paolo done. I just edited it

Comment: Did you forget to `import os`?

Comment: @Paolo I have os & boto3 installed. My bad, I ought to have added that part.

Comment: Tried with another region? What is the version of installed boto3? Can you print `REGION` variable and there is an expected value?

Comment: It's funny, but I changed the region in the environmental variable, yet the region kept showing me "eu-west-2"

Also, I don't know the boto3 version, as I am running the script in the AWS console directly. Not on VScode

Comment: Okay, I created a new function, and the region issue stopped. I will update the post now with my new error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you have an error on this line:

```
message = event['message']
```

Most likely the lambda event does not have the 'message' key you are expecting.  You should print out the event to CloudWatch Logs and take a look.

I ran the rest of your code and it created an EC2 instance successfully.